# Finding weekly count of authentication logs from oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below and i need to find the weekly count of the data.

```
Name                Null Type          
------------------- ---- ------------- 
DATE_ENTERED             VARCHAR2(100) 
TIME_ENTERED             VARCHAR2(100) 
USER_ID                  VARCHAR2(100) 
STATUS                   VARCHAR2(100) 
FAILEDLOGINATTEMPTS      VARCHAR2(100) 
ACCOUNTLOCKED            VARCHAR2(100) 
RESPONSECODE             VARCHAR2(100)
```

Can anyone advise me how to find the weekly count , daily count query is below.

```
(select "DATE", sum("SUCCESS COUNT") as "SUCCESS COUNT", sum("FAILURE 
COUNT") as "FAILURE COUNT", sum("LOCKED COUNT") as "LOCKED COUNT"
from (select to_char(to_date(date_entered,'YYYY-MON-DD'),'YYYY-MON-DD') as 
"DATE", decode(status,'Success',1,0) as "SUCCESS COUNT", 
decode(status,'Success',0,1) as "FAILURE COUNT", 
decode(accountlocked,'1',1,0) as "LOCKED COUNT" 
from invest_sixmonths  ) t1
group by "DATE") order by "DATE";
```

Comment: Why the hell do you use VARCHAR2 for DATE values?

Comment: The query you have, where you are deriving `to_char(to_date(date_entered||' '||TIME_ENTERED,'YYYY-MON-DD 
    HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MON-DD HH24') AS "DATE"`, is already for `hourly` data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not a good idea to use string columns for date datatypes, as it will give you similar kind of problems in future.

Now coming back to the problem, when you do a `to_char(to_date(date_entered||' '||TIME_ENTERED,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MON-DD HH24') AS "DATE"` then you are extracting only the `hour` part of a day from the `date` and `time` concatenation. So `group by` this derived column should give you your aggregated values `group by` hour.

For example

```
select to_char
        (to_date(
                    date_entered||' '||TIME_ENTERED,
                    'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS
                    ')
                    ,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24'
        ) 
from
(select '2017-JAN-01' as date_entered
           ,'21:43:54' as time_entered 
from dual)
```

this will give you `2017-JAN-01 21`, which you are using in `group by`. So you are already getting `hourly` result.

However, it would be better if you use `trunc` to extract `hour` like below

```
select  trunc(to_date(
                    date_entered||' '||TIME_ENTERED,
                    'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS
                    ')

        ,'HH24')
from
(select '2017-JAN-01' as date_entered
           ,'21:43:54' as time_entered 
from dual)
```

Output will be of datatype `date` and it would be truncated to nearest hour. On my client where `NLS_DATE_PARAMETER` is `DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS`, I see this.

```
23-JAN-17 21.00.00
```

Use this in `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRUNC()` to truncate the date to the start of the hour and then `GROUP BY` that:

```
SELECT TRUNC( TO_DATE( date_entered || time_entered, 'YYYY-MON-DDHH24:MI:SS' ), 'HH24' )
         AS "DATE",
       COUNT( CASE status WHEN 'Success' THEN 1 END ) AS success_count,
       COUNT( CASE status WHEN 'Success' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) AS failure_count,
       COUNT( CASE accountlocked WHEN '1' THEN 1 END ) AS locked_count
FROM   invest_logs
GROUP BY
       TRUNC( TO_DATE( date_entered || time_entered, 'YYYY-MON-DDHH24:MI:SS' ), 'HH24' )
ORDER BY
       "DATE"
```

You could also use `TO_CHAR()`:

```
TO_CHAR(
  TO_DATE( date_entered || time_entered, 'YYYY-MON-DDHH24:MI:SS' ),
  'YYYY-MON-DD HH24'
) AS "DATE",
```